# I want to lemmatize dask dataframe but I am stuck

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-delayed

I am new to dask and was wondering if anyone could give me a hand. I have a large text dataset >20GB and need/want to lemmatize a column. My current function - which works with pandas directly is

```py
wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()

def lemmatizing(sentence):    
    stemSentence = ""

    for word in sentence.split():
        stem = wnl.lemmatize(word)
        stemSentence += stem
        stemSentence += " "

    stemSentence = stemSentence.strip()

    return stemSentence
```

And usually would do the following

```py
df['news_content'] = df['news_content'].apply(lemmatizing)
```

I was looking at `delayed` but I am puzzled on how to implement it.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: dask also has an apply function.

Comment: Thanks. I guess what confused me was that ```.compute()``` resulted in an error.

Comment: Could you produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)?